# Recombine variables for different subgroups in Stata

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I have data where I need to do some calculations for different subgroups and then recombine them.

Each subgroup is defined by an equivalent weight of the household (OECD equivalent income scale).

Every new variable I generate follows this name pattern:

```
<varname><equivalentweight>
```

So the variable for the income divided by the equivalent weight 1.3 would be 
`income13`.

After computations in the different subgroups I want to recombine the results.

In this example I calculated the poverty threshold which is different for every subgroup and can now say who is poor in this subgroup. Now I want a variable which combines these results and shows who is poor in the population.

I know one way how to do this:

```
gen poor=.
recode poor .=1 if poor13==1 | poor15==1 | poor16==1 | poor18==1 ... 
recode poor .=0 if poor13==0 | poor15==0 | poor16==0 | poor18==0 ...
```

I guess there must be a faster way. I tried with loops (I just started coding loops yesterday) but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without having thought too hard about this, the following is equivalent to your code, which recodes an observation as poor if it is poor in any subgroup.

```
gen poor=.
recode poor .=1 if inlist(1,poor13,poor15,poor16,poor18, ... )
recode poor .=0 if inlist(0,poor13,poor15,poor16,poor18, ... )
```

Another approach that might meet your needs is

```
egen poor = rowmax(poor*)
```

With all that said, if my understanding is correct that each household has just one equivalent weight, and belongs to just subgroup, it is not clear to me that the approach you have taken to get to this point - creating a set of new variables of which only one will be relevant for any particular household - is not unduly complicated.

Comment: This seems along the right lines, except that any 1 tips the new variable to 1 and any 0 tips it back again. `gen poor = inlist(1, poor13, poor15, poor16, poor18)` might be enough,

Comment: It seems to me that if the first recode sets poor to 1 then the second recode will have no effect. In words, I understand the results to be 1 if any 1 is encountered, 0 if no 1 was encountered but a zero is encountered, and . if all are missing (or the only non-missing values are neither 1 nor 0). I agree that your single command will provide that result as well, and believe that my egen will do similarly, as long as 1, 0, and missing are the only values in the variables.

Comment: You're right, as each `recode` is confined to what is missing.